# sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, django

The "python manage.py syncdb" command is giving me the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I'm following the step by step instructions in Practical Django Projects, so I think this has to do something with the Windows Operating system acting quirky!

Things I've checkde: 
1.The path is updated in settings.py is absolutely correcto!
2. Path is : `C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop\Django\Database\cms\cms.txt`
  So the entire folder - Database, has sharing and security permissions.

I'm pretty much at the bottom of the ocean for not being able to follow and successfully execute simple instructions, so could you please help me out here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown exactly how the path is represented in your settings.py file. But if you've done it how you show here, it won't work. You need to use forward slashes (`/`) or double backwards slashes (`\\`).

This is because in Python a backslash usually means to escape the following character.

Comment: I just thought Python would take care of it by itself. Shud hv tried it! Thanks a ton!